# Best local data store for 34,000 rows

Tags: search, text-files

I'm on Win 7 pro and I've inherited a text file with 34,000 rows. I need to do some really basic searching and sorting on it.

I was going to use Excel, but it would bloat and die.

What's the simplest solution, short of loading the thing into my local SQL server, to throw this data into to do some simple searching?

Comment: MS Access can also be used. Just import the text file to a access table and do the search and sorting the way you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read text into a list or map (depending on what suits your needs better) then apply a sorting algorithm on the list.  Check out this list to find one that suits your needs.

[Sorting Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms)